# Printing Error - Stopped - The file '/private/var/spool/cups/tmp/...' could not be opened

Tags: macos, printing

When trying to print a PDF document using Preview (as well as printing any other document from any application), I'm getting the following error about how `Stopped - The file '/private/var/spool/cups/tmp/0076a5fa0ea54 could not be opened`.

Every time I print a new document the last section of the path changes.

I went into Terminal and listed the contents of that directory (`/private/var/spool/cups/tmp`) in sudo mode, and the file doesn't exist. Only one different file with a different name.

Tried restarting the computer, printer, and deleted the printer from macOS and re-added it.

Any ideas on how to fix this? I'm running macOS 10.15.7.

[image: Printer Error]

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me if this was another symptom of the issue HP have with their certificates having timed out this week. viz https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/404993/hp-easy-scan-hp-scanner-3-will-damage-your-computer https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/404944/stopping-false-positive-malware-warnings-in-catalina https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/404962/my-2017-imac-is-unable-to-print-but-my-old-mac-mini-prints-just-fine-any-insig

Answer (score 1):

There is a current problem with HP since they asked Apple to disable their software and then re-enable it.  You can change the driver to AirPrint and know it you need to apply updates and reinstall your print drivers if that works.

See my answer here for how to manually install a fix if you don’t want to let Apple software updates fix your HP.

- [HP Easy Scan - "HP Scanner 3" will damage your computer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/404993/)
- https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib/software12/HP_Quick_Start/osx/Installations/Essentials/hp-printer-essentials-S-5_14_8_4.pkg